# Finding the oldest employee doj is 1992

Tags: sql

can someone explain the below in bold(code)

```sql
    select pname, 
    case when dateadd(year, datediff(year, dob, getdate()), dob)>getdate() 
    then datediff(year, dob, getdate()) - 1 
    else datediff(year, dob, getdate()) 
    end as ageage from programmer 
    where dob = (select min(dob) from programmer where year(doj)='1992' and gender='f');
```

I honestly did not understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

The code below. Queries on a table called "programmer.

It begins by selecting the "pname" column from the table, which likely represents the name of the programmer.

The `case` part of the code calculates the age of each programmer based on their date of birth (dob). The case statement is used to handle the logic of calculating the age correctly.

The `dateadd(year, datediff(year, dob, getdate()), dob)` expression calculates the date of the current year using the programmer's date of birth. It determines the birthday of the current year by taking the difference between the current year and the programmer's birth year, adding it to the programmer's date of birth.

The `datediff(year, dob, getdate())` expression calculates the difference in years between the programmer's date of birth and the current date.

If the calculated birthday of the current year is greater than the current date, it means the programmer hasn't celebrated their birthday yet this year. In that case, the code subtracts 1 from the difference in years, giving the accurate age. Otherwise, it directly uses the difference in years as the age.

The result of this calculation is aliased as "ageage" in the output.

It then applies a condition to filter the rows returned. It restricts the result set to programmers who have their date of birth (dob) matching the minimum date of birth among the programmers meeting specific criteria.

The subquery `(select min(dob) from programmer where year(doj)='1992' and gender='f')` retrieves the minimum date of birth (dob) from the programmers who were born in 1992 and have a gender of 'f' (female).

Overall, the SQL code retrieves the name (pname) and calculated age (ageage) of the programmer(s) who have the minimum date of birth (dob) among those who were born in 1992 and are female.

```sql
select pname,
case
    when dateadd(year, datediff(year, dob, getdate()), dob) > getdate()
    then datediff(year, dob, getdate()) - 1
    else datediff(year, dob, getdate())
end as ageage
from programmer
where dob = (
    select min(dob)
    from programmer
    where year(doj) = '1992' and gender = 'f'
);
```